# Find a value in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there a way to find a value in DataTable in C# without doing row-by-row operation?

The value can be a part of (a substring of  row[columnName].value , separated by comma) a cell in the datatable and the value may be present in any one of columns in the row.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A DataTable or DataSet object will have a Select Method that will return a DataRow array of results based on the query passed in as it's parameter.

Looking at your requirement your filterexpression will have to be somewhat general to make this work.

```
myDataTable.Select("columnName1 like '%" + value + "%'");
```

Comment: how can we do the above syntax with linq.

Comment: how can you then use this Array as a DataSource for a ComboBox?

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you can filter rows by possible columns like this :

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = 
  datatable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", columnName, value));
```

Comment: if you want exact value: DataRow[] filteredRow = datatable.Select("ColumnName='value'");

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, there is nothing built in for searching all columns. You can use `Find` only against the primary key. `Select` needs specified columns. You can perhaps use LINQ, but ultimately this just does the same looping. Perhaps just unroll it yourself? It'll be readable, at least.

Answer (score -5):

this question asked in 2009 but i want to share my codes:

```
    Public Function RowSearch(ByVal dttable As DataTable, ByVal searchcolumns As String()) As DataTable

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    Dim bln As Boolean

    Dim dttable2 As New DataTable
    For x = 0 To dttable.Columns.Count - 1
        dttable2.Columns.Add(dttable.Columns(x).ColumnName)
    Next

    For x = 0 To dttable.Rows.Count - 1
        For y = 0 To searchcolumns.Length - 1
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchcolumns(y)) = False Then
                If searchcolumns(y) = CStr(dttable.Rows(x)(y + 1) & "") & "" Then
                    bln = True
                Else
                    bln = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If bln = True Then
            dttable2.Rows.Add(dttable.Rows(x).ItemArray)
        End If
    Next

    Return dttable2


End Function
```

Comment: This is a C# question, not VB.

Comment: and loops on rows and columns, something that the OP wants to avoid