# Check if a table contains overlapping timespans

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with two columns `FromDate` and `ToDate` , which are in string format.
I want to check if there are any duplicate records in my table.i.e

```
From Date    To Date
----------------------      
9/01/2012    9/16/2012   
8/23/2012    8/24/2012   
8/25/2012    8/25/2012   
8/5/2012     8/6/2012    
8/26/2012    8/27/2012   
9/15/2012    9/23/2012
```

The table contains duplicate records as their date range is mapping for

```
From Date       To Date      
----------------------      
9/01/2012    9/16/2012   
9/15/2012    9/23/2012
```

It should return false.

Comment: @Tisho :Thank you for editing.

Comment: Do you mean "exactly the same dates" or "overlapping timespans"?

Comment: @Mare Infinitus :Overlapping spans as shown in the example above

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            from row1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where
            (

                 (
                     DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("fromDate")) >= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("fromDate")) &&
                     DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("fromDate")) <= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("toDate"))
                 )
                 ||
                 (
                     DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("toDate")) >= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("fromDate")) &&
                     DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("toDate")) <= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("toDate"))
                 )
            )
            select new
            {
                fromDate = DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("fromDate")),
                toDate = DateTime.Parse(row1.Field<string>("toDate"))
            };
//This lst contains the dates which are overlapping    
var lst = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: good one, but that would be better if data in datatable would be in datetime format it will save DateTime.Parse for every record x 2.

Comment: @ Pravin : did u run the query..bcz when I am running it..the variable lst is showing 0, even when I have records :
    1st FromDate :8/1/2012     1st ToDate :8/2/2012
    2nd FromDate : 8/1/2012    2nd ToDate 8/11/2012

Comment: exactly, I get no results also.

Comment: example which I showed just compares fromDate & with < and not <= , Please change where clause as per your need

Answer (score 1):

Sort by `ToDate`, `FromDate` (or build a sorted array of indexes into your DataTable). Loop from row or array position #2 to the end and see if the FromDate <= to the previous item's ToDate. Place overlapping items into a list. Job done.

You can also sort by `FromDate`, `ToDate` and do similar logic.

Answer (score 1):

Okay then, a selfjoin will help here:

I have a small class TimePeriod, just to meet your needs

```
public class TimePeriod
{
    public int Id;
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public static DateTime Parse(string date)
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Parse(date, 
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

then I have some TestData

var list = new List();

```
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 1, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("9/01/2012"),  ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("9/16/2012") });
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 2, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/23/2012"), ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/24/2012") });
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 3, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/25/2012"), ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/25/2012") });
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 4, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/5/2012"), ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/6/2012") });
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 5, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/26/2012"), ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("8/27/2012") });
        list.Add(new TimePeriod() { Id = 6, FromDate = TimePeriod.Parse("9/15/2012"), ToDate = TimePeriod.Parse("9/23/2012") });
```

**And here is the solution:** (with some inspiration of OraNob, thanks for that)

```
var overlaps = from current in list
            from compare in list
            where
            (
            (compare.FromDate > current.FromDate &&
            compare.FromDate < current.ToDate) ||
            (compare.ToDate > current.FromDate &&
            compare.ToDate < current.ToDate)
            )
            select new
            {
                Id1 = current.Id,
                Id2 = compare.Id,
            };
```

Perhaps you want to leave out the second Id (as you will have duplicates 
here ( 1 / 6) and (6 / 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataTable.Search()` mehod to find out existence of any record in your `DataTable` this way you could enforce uniqueness in your records.

Something like this

```
string expression;
expression = "FromDate = #9/01/2012# AND ToDate = #9/16/2012#";
DataRow[] foundRows;

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = table.Select(expression);

if(foundRows.Length > 0)
     // Show duplicate message
else
    // Insert your new dates
```

For more [Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633819/how-to-find-a-value-in-datatable-in-c)

Comment: I dont have any expression.Records are already in the datatable.
I want to check if the existing records have any duplicate range value !!

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the "To Date" column and for each, search the "From Date" column for any earlier date that has a later corresponding "To Date".

Comment: A nested loop (CROSS JOIN with filter). Expensive!

Answer (score 0):

If you handle large datatables you should use @ErikE response. 
which needs more lines of code, but is definitely the most efficient by far.

If its small table and you prefer to compare each two rows.
you can use what other advised. 
just make sure to prevent row from being compared to itself, and duplicates in the result enumeration.

```
var query = from x in list
            where list.Exists((y) => x != y &&
                                     x.FromDate <= y.ToDate &&
                                     y.FromDate <= x.ToDate)
            select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strong textDeclare @Table Table  
(  
    RowId Int Identity(1, 1) Not Null, 
      Id NChar(3) Not Null, 
      StartDate DATETIME Not Null, 
      EndDate DATETIME Not Null 
);  

Insert Into @Table (Id, StartDate, EndDate)  
Select 'id1', '20131210 10:10', '20131220 10:10' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131211', '20131215' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131201', '20131205' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131206', '20131208' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131225 10:10', '20131225 10:11'
Select *  
From @Table;  


With Overlaps (OverlapRowId, BaseRowId, OStart, OEnd, BStart, BEnd)  
As  
(  
        Select Overlap.RowId, Base.RowId, Overlap.StartDate, Overlap.EndDate, Base.StartDate, Base.EndDate 
        From @Table As Base  
        Inner Join @Table As Overlap On Overlap.Id = Base.Id  
        Where (((Overlap.StartDate > Base.StartDate) And (Overlap.StartDate < Base.EndDate))
          Or ((Overlap.StartDate = Base.StartDate) And (Overlap.EndDate > Base.EndDate))) 
          And (Base.RowId != Overlap.RowId) 
) 
-- Remove records that were found to cause overlap issues.  
Delete T  
From @Table As T  
Inner Join  
(  
        Select O.OverlapRowId   
        From Overlaps As O 
        Left Join Overlaps As Fp On Fp.OverlapRowId = O.BaseRowId  
        Where (Fp.OverlapRowId Is Null) 
) As SubQuery On SubQuery.OverlapRowId = T.RowId;  

-- Select the valid options.  
Select RowId, Id, StartDate, EndDate  
From @Table where StartDate<EndDate;  
Go
```

Comment: Thank you so much , really appreciate your help with this. 

I have not come across the scenario where there are multiple records with the same start and enddates. that would be really help full if the data changes of the ID. 

Thank you!!!