# How can I get row index from tableadapter by cell value?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]I want to learn row index by cell value. I know cell value "E003". How can I learn row index that row include cell value "E003"? I need 7 not 11.

```
var table =TableAdapter.GetData();
var resultRow = table.Rows["I need row index. But I know just cell value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [TableAdapter Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.80).aspx) you can [get the underlying DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.80).aspx)  that you would like to query like this `var table = TableAdapter.GetData()`

#### Find Index of Row by searching a DataTable with a given value

The lines below show how you can find the Index of a certain row by Finding it via the primary key of that row. First you get a [collection of rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the DataTable and then you can use the method Find() to search a row by the given value.

```
DataRowCollection rowCol = GetDataTable().Rows; 
rowCol.Dump("Content for RowCollection: ");
// find row by value of primary key
// for it to work Emp_Code as to be set as primary key column
DataRow foundRow = rowCol.Find("E003"); 

int indexOfRow = rowCol.IndexOf(foundRow);
indexOfRow.Dump("zero based RowIndex is: ");
```

The underlying data looks similar to your screenshot

```
private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable("NameIsOptional");
   table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Emp_Id", typeof(int)));
   table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Emp_Code", typeof(string)));
   table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Name", typeof(string)));
   // set Column 'Emp_Code' as primary key column
   table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {table.Columns["Emp_Code"]};

   table.Rows.Add(1, "E001", "dave");
   table.Rows.Add(2, "E002", "mandle");
   table.Rows.Add(3, "E007", "sarana");
   table.Rows.Add(4, "E004", "poyekar");
   table.Rows.Add(5, "E005", "suryawanshi");
   table.Rows.Add(9, "E006", "survey");
   table.Rows.Add(11, "E003", "singh");

   return table;
}
```

Since you said little about the column `Emp_Code` i assume that it can be used as the primary key of the datatable.

#### Screenshot of linqpad demo programm

Below you can see the above code executed in linqpad

[image]

If you can not use `Emp_Code` as a primary key you may find the information you need in the question [How to find a value in DataTable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633819/how-to-find-a-value-in-datatable-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solition today like that.

```
            var table = TableAdapter.GetData().Select(s => new { s.Index })
                                  .AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select((s, counter) => new
                                  {
                                      s.Index,
                                      counter = counter + 1

                                  });

            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                if (item.Index == Emp_ID)
                {                        
                    //do something

                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I understand the following: `var table = TableAdapter.GetData()` returns a dataTable. The [`Select(...)`](http://goo.gl/c9BOF) returns an Array of DataRows. The parameter of `Select()` looks like  a [statement lambda](http://goo.gl/UgXQJ) `s=> new { s.Index}` although the `new` within this lambda confuses me and i can not figure out of what type the lambda expression `s => new { s.Index}`is or what it does. Trying your code out in Linqpad returns an error. Could you explain how your answer fits to your question to get the rowIndex of the Datagrid?