# Unable to figure out this (Statement) Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

I have come across a piece of code that i can not figure out and that even might not work. Below you can find the code.

#### The Code i try to figure out in context

The method `GetDataTableData()` returns a [`System.Data.DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) the method [`Select(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) returns an array of [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) Objects: `DataRow[] rows`. As far as i can tell the lambda within the Select() is invalid.

```
    var table = GetDataTableData()
                 .Select(s => new { s.Index })
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(
                     (s, counter) => new { s.Index, counter = counter + 1 }
                 );
```

#### My Question: What does this lambda do - is it even valid / working?

The method [`Select(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) has several overloads that all start with type string.

- Can a lambda expression be of type string?
- What is the return type of a lambda - always a delegate?

Here the lines in question from above

```
    // of what type is this (a delegate?)
    s => new { s.Index } 
    ... 
    // and what does this
    (s, counter) => new { s.Index, counter = counter + 1 }
```

#### Update after reading the answers below

As far as i understood at least the second Select refers to [`IEnumerable.Select<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) .But calling `AsEnumerable()` on the collection does not change the underlying type:

```
    // calling AsEnumberable() does not change type
    IEnumerable<DataRow> enumDataRows = GetDataTable().AsEnumerable();
    Type type = enumDataRows.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
    type.Dump(); // still returns DataRow
```

Therefore the property Index must exist in the underlying type for the lambda expression `(s) => { return new { s.Index }; }` to work.

**Is this assumption correct?**

#### Regarding the first select

How do i recognize that it is the build in `Select()` or a Enumerable Method `Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>`

- either the [`IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)
- or the [`IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)

None the less i assume that the statement is still not valid, since the tSource underlying object DataRow has no property `Index`:

```
    var tResult = GetDataTable().Select(
                      (tSource, tResult) => { return new { tSource.Index }; }
                      );
```

**Is this assumption correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are lambdas that result in anonymous objects. Also, both are written in a very terse form, the complete form would be:

```
(s) => { return new { s.Index }; }
```

The second is equivalent.

Both lambdas are `Func<>` delegates, with varying signatures.

A lambda can result in a string, but that depends on what you are using it for (type inference is a huge thing here and one of the reasons lambdas are very terse).

The return type of a lambda depends on the context you are using it in - it can be a delegate, but in your case, it isn't. A lambda is a delegate though - if it has a return type, it's a `Func<T1, T2, ... Tn, TReturn>`, if it doesn't, it's `Action<T1,T2,..., Tn>`.

Comment: As far as i understand it `s` represents the object that goes into the lambda expression and inside the lambda a anonymous object is created that has only the index as a property. Does this lambda  `(s) => { return new { s.Index }; }` return a `Func<T, int, TResult>` datatype?

Comment: No, it returns an object of type `TResult`, an anonymous class in this case. A lambda **is** a `Func<>` or `Action<>`.

Comment: So i could interpret as `var myResult = (s) => { return new { s.Index }; }` and return object  `myResult` is of type `TResult` and this could be of type string?

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` you're using is [`IEnumerable.Select<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx), since the return value of [AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Do you mean the second one from this line `.Select( (s, counter) => new { s.Index, counter = counter + 1 });` or do you mean the first one as well?

Comment: Both are `IEnumerable<T>` extension method. The first one project rows into an anonymous object using the `Index` property and the second one attach the index of the element in the sequence. The `count` parameter is getting the index of the iteration (from `0` to `N-1`). So what the whole thing does it attaching the Index value to the 1-based index of the element in the collection.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Oh, I meant the second one. Is the return type of `GetDataTableData()` exactly the type `DataTable` or something inheriting from `DataTable`?

Comment: I am not certain if GetDataTableData() is exactly of type DataTable. I only know what is provided in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525809/how-can-i-get-row-index-from-tableadapter-by-cell-value)

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Since `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, I can't see the first select working without an `AsEnumerable()` call which converts it to an `IEnumerable<T>`. Once it's converted, it will propagate through the selects (as long as they're valid) as an `IEnumerable<T>`. As for the `Index` property, I can't see where it would possibly come from either.